# Passing a named parameter not working in boost

Tags: boost

[The Boykov Kolmogorov Max Flow algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.html) has several named parameters. Somehow I'm having trouble passing these parameters to the function.

When I do something like

```
boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, origin, sink, edge_capacity(get(edge_capacity, g)));
```

then I'm getting:

```
error: ‘edge_capacity’ cannot be used as a function
```

(Nb: I know that the above invocation makes no sense but it shows what is going wrong.)

I know I can probably use `get(edge_capacity, g)` to get the capacity map and work with that instead of passing in my own. I'm just in general interested in whether there is a rule about when I can specifically pass in a named parameter and when not even though the boost specification specifically mentions the named parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very much as if you are using names in conflicting roles, namely `edge_capacity`.

From http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp it seems that you might have to use `capacity_map`:

Try

```
boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, origin, sink, boost::capacity_map(get(edge_capacity, g)));
```

If that works, this looks like a documentation bug

---

**UPDATE** Yes, this appears to be the case. Refer to the documentation of [`edmonds_karp_max_flow`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/edmonds_karp_max_flow.html) for example, where the corresponding named parameter is documented as:

> **IN:** `capacity_map(CapacityEdgeMap cap)`
>
> The edge capacity property map. The type must be a model of a constant Lvalue Property Map. The key type of the map must be the graph's edge descriptor type.
>
> **Default:** `get(edge_capacity, g)`

Comment: I can confirm - using `capacity_map` works. Same issue with `edge_residual_capacity`.